# Removing filename from url with htaccess

Tags: url, url-rewriting

I have a single page website

http://picniclounge.com/parallax-page/index.html

I would like it to read picniclounge.com/ and not with the folder and index.html at the end.

How can I do this using htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in your htaccess:

```
 DirectoryIndex /parallax-page/index.html
```

Comment: Elegant solution if this is the only index.html within the parallax-page folder. Dangerous if not ;-)